# include wp-blog-header not working on MAMP

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, wpdb, include, wp-blog-header.php

To clarify my question...
My plugin is/was using AJAX to call the file `pluginname/submit/pick.php`  My `pluginname/pluginname.php` contains the usual plugin header and wordpress automatically finds it.

Original Question...
I'm trying to use the global `$wpdb` in a plugin to insert data into one of my tables.
From the docs it sounds like I just need to include `wp-blog-header.php`
However when I try to do so I'm getting an error.

> **PHP Fatal error:** [`require()`](function.require) : 
>   Failed opening required 'http://localhost:8888/blog/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/submit/pick.php on line 4

My `pluginname/submit/pick.php` (which is called by AJAX) has the following code

```
<?php
    $p = 'http://localhost:8888/blog/wp-blog-header.php';
    echo $p;
    require($p);
    echo 'hi';
?>
```

If I load the `pick.php`, I see `http://localhost:8888/blog/wp-blog-header.php` and that is it.  So it must be failing on the require, as the error log confirms.

The path is correct as I inserted a quick echo into `wp-blog-header.php`, and copy pasted the output from `pick.php` into the address bar and it worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer**

The error is because I put a URL in instead of a filepath.  and the one line fix is to set `$p = '../../../../wp-blog-header.php';`

**The long answer**

Following kaiser's link led me down a long road that eventually lead to what I believe is the correct way to do this.

in `pluginname/plugin.php`

```
// load your javascript, and setup the ajaxurl variable
// this is loading my js everywhere, we could load it only where needed
// 0.01 is the version of your js, increment this each time you change your js
//   so that you don't keep using the same cached version
wp_enqueue_script( 'pluginname', plugins_url( 'js/pluginname.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), 0.01 );
wp_localize_script( 'pluginname', 'pluginname', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

// wp_ajax_insert_pick is a combination of wp_ajax_ and the 'action' : 'insert_pick' you provide in your js
// ajax_insert_pick is the function below that is called to handle your ajax request 
add_action( "wp_ajax_action_name", "ajax_insert_pick" );

// this basically replaces pluginname/submit/pick.php
function ajax_insert_pick() {
    global $wpdb;
    $var = $_POST['var'];
    // handle the ajax request here
    echo $response;
    die(); // needed otherwise wordpress may append a zero to your response.
}
```

in `pluginname/js/pluginname.js`

```
function submit_pick( var ) {
    jQuery.post( pluginname.ajaxurl, 
                 { 'action' : 'insert_pick',
                   'var' : var },
                 function(response) {
                     alert(response); },
                 'text' );
}
```

Since I just learned this last night, and am only a month into learning php/mysql/wp/js/ajax there are quite possibly some errors in the above.  But it worked for me last night, so I'm happy with it at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

You're making something completely wrong.

### Header comment

In your main file, you need the following comment on top (ex. taken from Contact form 7):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Contact Form 7
Plugin URI: http://contactform7.com/
Description: Just another contact form plugin. Simple but flexible.
Author: Takayuki Miyoshi
Author URI: http://ideasilo.wordpress.com/
Text Domain: wpcf7
Domain Path: /languages/
Version: 3.1.2
*/
```

WP will detect the plugin automagically. Then simply `define/require/include` what you need. The plugin will then be loaded just before the `plugins_loaded` hook, which is the first one available to you. You then can use the complete WP environment.

Comment: thanks for the reply,  I wasn't specific enough in my question.  the pluginname/submit/pick.php is just one of multiple files in my plug-in.  It is called through AJAX to insert something in the database.

Comment: Here's the archive to make it right: [tag:ajax]. **PLUS** Edit your Q to reflect that fact.